# Onchange firing over and over again in chrome but not FireFox

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

I have a simple upload form that collects files and stores them, then updates a div on the page with a list of the uploaded files (not the same div that the input control is in). The javascript is triggered by:

```
onchange="UploadFile(<?=$_GET["id"]?>)")
```

Everything works just fine in FireFox and Internet Explorer but in Chrome it's triggered like 20 times resulting in 20 rows with the same filename and 5-7 files uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong with Chrome. Can you show the code for uploading the file?

I always used Chrome for my default browser, and nothing goes wrong here.

here is the proof

http://jsfiddle.net/3ZE7Z/

`<form>
    <input type='text' onchange='alert("change!");'>
</form>`

Edit: Make sure you have the latest version of Chrome. By default, Chrome will check for update and update itself

Comment: Hi. I asked to post the code from my boss but I got denied as it contains rows of code that were produced here at work.

All I can say is that it works in IE, FF but not in chrome as the onchange gets triggered over and over when the code adds extra info to another <div> on the page

Comment: @PatrikBlåLindqvist there is nothing wrong with Chrome's onchange DOM event. I you can't show the code, we can't help to debug it.